# Toyota Aygo, power steering

Tags: toyota, power-steering

I’ve had my 61 plate Toyota for 6 months, and within them 6 months my power steering has gone 3 times. I took it back to where I bought it, they said the battery wasn’t strong enough to power the car, so they changed my battery. The 2nd time they said it was because some wires had come loose under the carpet near my feet. The 3rd time, they said the control box was faulty, so they gave me a whole new control box. My question is: Will my steering be ok now that they have replaced the control box?

Comment: Note to those who aren't in UK: 61 plate means late 2011 or very early 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. There are several parts in an electric power steering system:

- Alternator (although you'd probably know already if it was failing)
- Battery
- Lots of wiring
- Torque sensor
- Control module / box
- The motor itself

What they haven't changed yet is the motor and the sensor. I'd say you have a fair chance of the problem being resolved, but if you're unlucky, the problem could be in the parts that haven't been replaced yet.